# f.write error. Must be str not resultnet

Tags: python, string, csv, typeerror

hello im having trouble regarding f.write.
Ive webscraped from Newegg.com and now I would like to f.write a loop to a csv file.

code:

```
filename='NeweggWebscrape.csv'
f=open(filename,'w')

headers='ProductName,Details,Delivery\n'

f.write(headers)

for namedesc in name_desc:
    ProductName = namedesc.text.strip()

    features= page_soup.findAll ('ul', {'class' : 'item-features'})
    Details=feature.text.strip()

    shipping=page_soup.findAll ('li', {'class' : 'price-ship'})
    Delivery=shippinginfo.text.strip()

    print('Name' + ProductName)
    print('Details' + Details)
    print('Delivery' + Delivery)

f.write (ProductName + "," + Details.replace(",", "|") + "," + shipping + "\n")

f.close()
```

However the error that im getting in powershell is:

```
File "neweggwebscrape.py", line 76, in <module>
    f.write (ProductName + "," + Details.replace(",", "|") + "," + shipping + "\n")
TypeError: must be str, not ResultSet
```

Ive tried to fix it but im a little stuck if anyone can help.

Much thanks

Joseph

Comment: `shipping` is not a string but a set of results. You must convert it to a string before concatenating with the other strings.

Comment: thank you, how do I do that? new to python. thnx

Answer (score 0):

`shipping` is not a string but a set of results. You must convert it to a string before concatenating with the other strings. Judging by your code, you want to extract the text part of each list item. After doing so, you have to join the pieces. The following code uses a comma for joining, you can use any other string:

```
shippinginfo = ",".join(s.text.strip() for s in shipping)
```

Comment: where do I add that? thank you.. i'm so confused. its my first day :/

Comment: Just after the line where you define `shipping`.

Comment: thank you so much that worked:) now I have a permission error.   File "neweggwebscrape.py", line 57, in <module>
    f=open(filename,'w')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'NeweggWebscrape.csv'

Comment: Since it is a different question, you have to make a different post with a different code example. From what I can tell, you try to create a file in a folder that you are not allowed to modify.